# Add Youtube Subscribe Button using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, youtube

I am attempting to add a youtube subscribe button dynamically to my site like so:

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js"></script>
<div id="youtubeContainer"></div>       
...
window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById("youtubeContainer").innerHTML = ('<div class="g-ytsubscribe" data-channel="GoogleDevelopers" data-layout="default" data-count="default"></div>');
}
```

But the button is not visible. I am wondering if there is a way to load a youtube subscribe button dynamically so I can enter a new channel name/id?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is already working. I think problem in other code of your page.

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js"></script>
<div id="youtubeContainer"></div>    
<script>

    document.getElementById("youtubeContainer").innerHTML = ('<div class="g-ytsubscribe" data-channel="GoogleDevelopers" data-layout="default" data-count="default"></div>');

</script>
```

**[JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/yukiwosika/edit?html,css,output)**

[EDIT]

**With window onload :**

```
function renderYtSubscribeButton(channel) {
      var container = document.getElementById('youtubeContainer');
      var options = {
        'channel': channel,
        'layout': 'default'
      };
      gapi.ytsubscribe.render(container, options);
    }

window.onload = function() {
renderYtSubscribeButton("GoogleDevelopers");
}  

</script>
```

**[JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/tuhizukoti/edit?html,css,output)**

Comment: But then how can I add my own url? I need to add the button after loading a channel name from a database.

Comment: What you use for getting channel name from a database? if you use server side script, then works fine

Comment: The client fetches the URL from a mySQL database.

Comment: Yes, but which scripting language you are using for fetching URL from database. for example, if use PHP, then write the code in php to connect mysql and fetch url form database and add the url in javascript by passing php variable into javascript. in this case above code working perfect. because of server side script execute first

Comment: The server is a Node.js server. And the data is fetched in the window.onLoad

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113202/discussion-between-rohit-goyani-and-user3024235).

Answer (score 0):

Many Youtubers having their personal websites want to add channel subscription button on their website, Below is the step by step guide on adding a youtube subscribe button on your website.
Step 1) Go to https://developers.google.com/youtube/youtube_subscribe_button.

Step 2) Enter your Channel Id in the text box.

Step 3) Select the Layout of Button

Step 4) Select the Theme.

Step 5) Subscriber Count(shown or hidden)

Step 6) Get the code & paste into your Website.
*Read More..*[How to add Youtube Subscribe button in Javascript](http://itgiggs.in/how-to-add-youtube-subscribe-button-on-website/)